# How remove <a> tag-content in the content field before indexing/stored in Solr

Tags: html, solr

I index some html-documents with solr 6.6.0. There is a lot of Link-text in the content field, which dilute the search results. So, how do I remove the  tag-content in the "content"-field befor indexing/storing in Solr? Is there a way about the updateRequestProcessorChain? Anybody knows a solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem by adding before and after the text a hidden div:

```
<div style="display:hidden">1%%A</div>
   TEXT TEXT TEXT
<div style="display:hidden">1%%E</div>
```

and add to the solrconfig.xml:

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="myregex">
   <processor class="solr.RegexReplaceProcessorFactory">
       <str name="fieldName">mytextfield</str>
       <str name="pattern">([1]{1}%{2}[A]{1})(.*)([1]{1}%{2}[E]{1})</str>
       <str name="replacement"> </str>
       <bool name="literalReplacement">true</bool>
   </processor>
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use `HTMLStripCharFilterFactory` as filter in your field definition during index time.

This Char Filter strips HTML from the input stream

```
<analyzer>
 <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
 <tokenizer ...>
 [...]
</analyzer>
```

Comment: The HTMLStripCharFilterFactory strips only the Tags, not the Content between. But I need to remove all the Navigation Link Text.